# Automatically find license of music

Tags: automation, music, database, license, api

Is there some kind of database or online API that would enable me to automatically find the license for a certain music album?

I would like to legally share music with some friends, but my collection is too large to look up the license of every album.

Comment: Licencing isn't for personal use (de facto). What way do you want to share the music?

Comment: I'd like to offer FLAC files to be downloaded from my server. And I'm pretty sure "sharing with friends" is not "_personal_ use".